# Premeasure and induced outer measure exercise.

Tags: measure-theory, outer-measure

I'm solving the following exercise from Folland's Real Analysis book:

[image]

I have done everything except **item (c)**, I can't find a way to prove it, any hints?

Comment: If $X=\cup_n A_n$ with $A_n\in \mathcal{A}$ and $\mu_0(A_n)<\infty$, then for an arbitrary $A\subset X$ we have that $A$ is $\mu^*$-measurable iff $A\cap A_n$ is $\mu^*$-measurable for every $n$.

Comment: @Jose27 I understand that if $A\subset X$ is $\mu^*$-measurable, then each $A\cap A_n$ is $\mu^*$-measurable, but I don't understand why the converse is true.

Comment: Hint: $\mu^*$-measurable sets form a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Oh yes, thanks, I'm so tired that I didn't think of using that. I'll try to work item (c) out using this fact now.

Comment: I'm stuck with this: For each $A\cap A_n$, from item (b) we have that there is a $B_n\in \mathcal{A}_{\sigma\delta}$ such that $A\cap A_n\subset B_n$ and $\mu^*(B_n\setminus [A\cap A_n]) = 0$, but I don't see how to get a $B\in\mathcal{A}_{\sigma\delta}$ for $A$.

Comment: I managed to complete the proof, thanks @Jose27